# Which European Union countries can an Indian citizen with Georgian temporary residence visit without advance application for a visa?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, europe, georgia-country, residency

I'm an Indian citizen and do have an **Indian passport**, presently studying in Georgia, and I possess a **temporary resident visa of Georgia** for a duration of **5 years** which was allotted for **study purposes**. Yearly we will be getting vacations. So I was thinking about visiting possible countries which I can visit without the requirement of a visa. So if someone could help me out with the list of countries which an Indian passport holder with temporary residence of Georgia can visit, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 8):

Georgia is not a member of the EU or EEA, so residence there does not really help you as far as visa exemptions are concerned.

You can also obtain an e-Visa for the neighboring countries of Armenia and Azerbaijan.

Otherwise, from checking Timatic and Wikipedia, you will need to obtain a visa in advance for anywhere else in Europe.

Comment: A minor point: neither Serbia nor Ukraine are members of the European Union.

Comment: @CannonFodder I interpreted the question as "where in Europe," since many people don't understand what the EU actually is. I leave it to the OP as to whether my answer is useful or not.

Comment: This is no longer true, Serbia requires visas from Indian citizens, starting from January 1, 2023. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens

Answer (score 3):

As of 2023, the only European countries that are visa-free for holders of Indian passports are **Albania** and **Moldova**. Both are quite "off the beaten track", so it'll require some research to get there without crossing any other countries which require visas from Indians (some Schengen countries - not all of them! - even require Airport Transit Visas from Indian passport holders).

If we use a wider definition of Europe, then you can also visit **Northern Cyprus** visa-free. Additionally, **Armenia** and **Azerbaijan** can be visited with an eVisa.

Your Georgian visa doesn't help you at all. A Schengen visa or a United States visa (or residence permits) would help you in some European countries.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements.aspx)(this version on the Emirates web site) you'll need a visa to enter Britain, Ireland and the Schengen area countries. That's the major EU countries - I haven't checked the rest, but it's likely to be similar. If you have a specific destination in mind, please edit into your question.

[Edit]
I've checked the remaining EU countries and Switzerland - none will allow you to visit without a visa. Your Georgian residency doesn't help you.

You might find [this list](https://www.indianholiday.com/blog/countries-you-can-visit-indian-passport/) of countries that offer visa-free or visa-on-arrival travel for Indian citizens.

If you're thinking about a non-european destination in mind you can check the visa requirements yourself on the Timatic page I linked above.